# Legality of posting dictated video of publisher's slides

Tags: presentation

I typically will write my own slides for a course, and then may make a screen recorded video of me talking over the slides. Now I'm planning on doing a screen recording over slides the publisher has included with our textbook, and posting the video to our learning platform (D2L, Moodle, etc.). I do have to edit the slides before doing this. Is there any legal issue here at any level?

What if I remove the annoying copyright at the bottom of the (title) slide(s)?

Comment: Don't remove the copyright notice.

Comment: @Adam any particular insight here?

Comment: Well, it is illegal. See also https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap5.html

Comment: What is specific to mathematics education about this question? It might be better to ask on Academia Stack Exchange or perhaps Law.

Comment: Please post answers as answers, not as comments. Thanks! @Adam

Comment: Can  you ask the publisher? If you had their permission there would be no question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't specific to Mathematics Education, but belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - either Law or Academia.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question of intellectual property law, not one of mathematics education.  You need to ask an IP lawyer---your department may have some legal consul you can speak wit;, it is a Bad Idea™ to follow legal advice provided by randos on the internet with zero qualifications. You could also try [law.se].

Answer (score 1):

Some relevant sections from https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap5.html

> (c) Fraudulent Copyright Notice.—Any person who, with fraudulent
>   intent, places on any article a notice of copyright or words of the
>   same purport that such person knows to be false, or who, with
>   fraudulent intent, publicly distributes or imports for public
>   distribution any article bearing such notice or words that such person
>   knows to be false, shall be fined not more than \$2,500.
>
> (d) Fraudulent Removal of Copyright Notice.—Any person who, with
>   fraudulent intent, removes or alters any notice of copyright appearing
>   on a copy of a copyrighted work shall be fined not more than \$2,500.

I am not a lawyer, but you should consider that 'not more than \$2500' might be interpreted as a per incident cap. i.e. per student, or worse, per download.

Now, the publisher will probably give you wide latitude fine with their material, but you should contact them for details and permission.

Comment: I guess a key term is "fraudulent intent", but I am not a lawyer either and I suspect that the question would be a better fit for Law Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JW I also do not know how liberal of an interpretation to take here. Regardless, I think that the correct answer should be to read the publisher's licence, ask if other permissions are needed, and avoid anything that is close to copyright violation or plagiarism.